# Get address of system function manually?

Tags: c, gdb, system

How do I obtain the address that GDB gives when I do "print system"?

Supposedly, if I start the program and then immediately pause it, then look in /proc/$pid/maps and get the base address of the library. Then I need to find the offset of system() in libc.so.6 and add these two together. However, when I try this in practice, I end up with an address different than the one gdb gives.

What's the best way to obtain system() address?

Please note that I'm trying to obtain address of another program, not the one that I compiled myself.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: By offset do you mean file-offset of the code or a virtual address? Do you understand the difference?

Comment: on linux, function pointers can converted to a void *. So e.g. `void *ptr = system; printf("%p\n", ptr);` Though that might not solve what you're actually trying to do. `

Comment: @nos He probably wants to hack into another process and make it spawn some other process. Another oiption: something with his own `system` call doesn't work, so he's looking for anomalies. If so, then he's probably looking in a wrong place.

Comment: @nos i think this way address of `system` stub in current executable will be printed

Comment: Yes, it's for buffer overflow. Anyone has any ideas on how GDB gets the address tho?

Comment: @Dabo So you don't want that ? Then what do you want ?

Comment: I want the address of system() function inside libc.so.6.

Comment: What you where doing is correct. Did you have ALSR enabled?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to obtain system() address?

```
#include <stdio.h>    // printf()
#include <stdlib.h>   // system()
...

...
   {
   int rCode=0;
   int (*system_ptr)(const char *command) = system;
   ...
   rCode=(*system_ptr)("echo \"hello\"");
   ...
   printf("Address of system(): %p\n", system_ptr);
   ...
   }
...
```

Comment: This will likely print address of a stub in current image and not address of actual code. ie. adresses obtained in different images in the same process will be different.

Comment: This returns the PLT address of system, not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Havent tried it, but have just an idea. How about:

```
void* libc = dlopen("libc.so");
void* address = dlsym( libc, "system");
```

?

Comment: It returned 0xb7e9af10. Address GDB gives is 0xb7e9ef10. Pretty close.

Comment: Can you please check what's under any of those adresses? Perhaps one of them contains just a jump instruction to the other? Btw. why do you really want to have the value exactly as gdb shows it?

Comment: I'm doing ret2libc and only the address of function inside GDB works.
When I compile this and run it, it gives me 0xb7e9af10. When I open this program in gdb and do 'p system'I get the same address (0xb7e9af10).

But when I open other files and do "p system" I get 0xb7e9ef10.

Comment: In your program both my code and gdb agree, so there is no confusion. In program you want to hack, the address of system seems to be diffrent, and since it's not your program you cannot use my code to confirm it - do I understand the situation right? First I would check `/proc/$pid/maps` to see if your program has the same base addres for libc as hacked program. Probably some other lib has alread taken part of libc address space, so libc needed to be relocated and thus the change.

Comment: ~Just wanted to check my system for different loading adresses of libc: I run `for i in \`ls /proc | grep [0-9]\\\+\`; do cat /proc/$i/maps | grep "libc-"; done | grep 00000000 | sort | uniq | wc -l` and it shows 34 difrerent base adresses for different processes. Guess ASLR is guilty here - did you disable it?

Comment: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/hh-10.html
Scroll down and you'll see that they tried to get the system address same way you did and ended up with different ones. Don't exactly understand which address they end up with after they get the offset.

Comment: They end up with different adresses because they use different programs (fa and fa2), and fa2 links to libdl that gets linked before libc. Therefore libdl gets offset that in fa belonged to libc, and libc in fa2 needs to be relocated after libdl - hence different adresses. Genrally if you do ret2libc you should know exact version of software used in hacked environment (this shouldn't be difficult if they use a known distribution), and using the same software on your machine get the specific address for your case.